# Cancel DragGesture in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I need a way to cancel/end a drag gesture if the user drags let's say more than 100px.

Is there a way to do it?

```
@GestureState private var dragOffsetState  = CGSize.zero

DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
    .updating($dragOffsetState) { value, state, transaction in
        state = value.translation
        // something like 
        // if value.translation.width > 100 { state = .canceled }
        // after this onEnded should be called
                                
    }
    .onEnded({ gesture in
                                
        if abs(gesture.translation.width) > 100 {
            UINotificationFeedbackGenerator().notificationOccurred(.error)
        } else {
            UINotificationFeedbackGenerator().notificationOccurred(.success)
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: You can achieve this by checking whether the drag distance has gone above 200px, If yes you can set offset to zero otherwise set offset to `value.translation`. You can use that offset in your component.
If you want I can provide you code in answer section.

Comment: @FaaizDaag I've tried but it doesn't seem to work... I can just keep dragging

Answer (score 1):

```
struct GestureDemo: View {
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.red)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .offset(offset)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        if abs(value.translation.width) > 200 {
                            offset = .zero
                        } else {
                            offset = value.translation
                        }
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        offset = .zero
                    }
            )
    }
}
```

I checked whether the drag distance has gone above this limit. If so, the gesture is stopped by setting the offset to zero. If not, the offset is adjusted to reflect the most recent drag distance.

Comment: Is there a way to end the gesture from inside `.onChanged` so that  `.onChanged` is no longer called? (other than using a flag to do it manually)